# Facing issues with interrupts in STM32L452RET6P

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

Interrupts are not working as expected when jumping from one application to another one. I use STM32L452RET6P micro controller and doing baremetal programming

I face some issue with the interrupts of STM32L452RET6P. I have two codes running in the controller one is a custom bootloader code and other is an application code which stored in flash memory. when the device get reset it will run the custom bootloader application which is at 0x08000000. It uses TIMER6 and UART2 in interrupts with 1 and 2 priority respectively. As per the flow if there is no uart interrupts triggered with in the defined time the device will jump to the application code which is at a different flash location. This works fine for me, and the application code also starts running,

But the interrupts are not triggering, I use RTC wakeup, UART2, TIMER6 and EXTI interrupts in the application code with priorities 1,2,3 and 4 respectively, my code is stuck in the while(1). Issue is only with interrupts, I checked with and LED Blink code it works fine.

what may be the reason for this issue?

Comment: Are you using the same vector table for the bootloader as for the application? Or some setup with different ones? And the obvious: did you enable interrupts through the global interrupt mask, `cpsie i` or equivalent?

Comment: Does your code jump to application from interrupt handler triggered by bootloader? Timer interrupt? In that case, your MCU is already executing interrupt, since it never properly exited bootloader's timer interrupt. If that's the case, you need to jump from thread execution mode or manually exit interrupt straight to application with a bit of assembly magic (link register magic value)

Comment: Since the problem is clearly with your bootloader code, you really do have to post that code (at least the relevant parts of it involving the "jump" to your application) if you expect an answer that is not simply a guess.

Comment: which isrs are you wanting to use the ones in the bootloader or application?  does this core allow for vtor to change (not all of them do!)(trivial experiment to find out, read the docs) and if so did you change vtor?

Comment: Is it possible your bootloader is not relevant to your problem?  You spend a lot of time on that in your question, but ultimately it is your application code that is not working.  The bootloader is possibly a distraction.  Your question cannot be answered without showing the code. Otherwise you are just asking for guesses regarding _"what may be the reason for this issue?"_ where without information, the possible reasons are numerous.  How do you know what you are saying happens is true?  What debugging actions have you taken (inspect NVIC registers fie example)?

Comment: You mention  "the while(1) loop" as if we all know _the_ exact loop you are referring to.  You forgot to post the code you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

How do you perform the jump to the application?  Have you ensured that the application is using the correct vector table, and not the bootloader's?

You will have to (at least) disable the NVIC, reset/disable any peripherals used by the bootloader, relocate the vector table to that of the application, then set the SP and PC to those in the application vector table.

The basic steps of that I have previously covered at   [Bootloader for STM32F405 Not Jumping to Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315852/bootloader-for-stm32f405-not-jumping-to-application/44317315#44317315)

To guarantee the application starts with all peripherals in the expected reset state, it is safest to have the bootloader issue a reset via the NVIC, before starting the application.  Because the SRAM is maintained during a reset, you can set a pattern in a reserved area in SRAM to indicate the bootloader should jump straight to the application without performing any peripheral initialisation or flash update.  You need of course to reset that SRAM signature to ensure you can update on a subsequent reset.

Comment: I use different vector tables for each application. Before jumping I disabled all interrupts deinit the peripherals also. My application started running and stuck in while(1). If I make a reset via NVIC it will come back to the bootloader code which is at 0x08000000, I don't think that will solve my issue.

Comment: @SuhaibSaiyde Then, my comment on the question applies.  Insufficient information.  You cannot simply say (in effect):  _"I am doing everything correct and it does not work, why?"_, because clearly you are not, and you have not shown what you are actually doing.  That said, you have clearly misunderstood my recommendation about resetting to start the application.  You do have the modify the bootloader to achieve that.  It is simpler and less error prone than "de-initialisation".